# nginx + node.js в сети выдает ошибку 403 а по локалке нет

Tags: node.js, nginx, администрирование

Использую nginx + node.js

server:

```js
const fastify = require('fastify')({
    logger: true
  })
  
  fastify.get('/', async (request, reply) => {
    reply.type('application/json').code(200)
    return { hello: 'world' }
  })
  
  fastify.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', function (err, address) {
    if (err) throw err
    fastify.log.info(`server listening on ${address}`)
  })
```

nginx:

---default:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name example.ru www.example.ru;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
    }
}
```

nginx.conf - пытался менять user www-data; на что угодно.. и руты и другие пользователи... толку нет... с локалки захожу спокойно а вот из вне из сети ошибка `403 Forbidden Web server`

буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: «Forbidden Web server» — может это какая-то прокси? Ни в nginx ни в nodejs такой ошибки нет.

Comment: И вообще как у вас настроен доступ извне?

Comment: nginx у меня настроен как прокси. в роутере раскидан NAT + у провайдера взял белый ip и открыл порты в ufw. это проблема в nginx 100% так как я ставил стандартные настройки где открывается дефолтная страница "добро пожаловать в NGINX" и все равно в локалке ее видно а из сети нет

Comment: 80 порт у провайдеров часто закрыт. Уточните в техподдержке своего провайдера

Comment: а давайте я попробую на прямую пустить через 3000 порт... 1 сек

Comment: Нашел в чем причина была... невнимательность да глупость... NAT был разброшен на другое подключение... дело в том что белый ip у моего провайдера требовал PPTP а сам интернет без авторизации.